# batch file to copy new files over since last time it ran

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a batch file that copies items from one folder to another, but only copies new items since last time batch file checked.....I cant used the standard /XN or /D because those check the destination folder for the latest files....my destination folder will grab those files and process them and delete them......so if I use those commands it will keep copying everything since it wont see any files... I need something that keeps track of when last time it checked and only copy new files since then.

This is what I have so far(but only copies anything newer than 1 day.)

```
robocopy "C:\Source" "C:\Destination" /MAXAGE:1
```

Need something like this

last time checked = time;
if files times > last time checked then copy
otherwise don't copy
last time checked = update to new current time

Comment: XCOPY and ROBOCOPY have a feature that only copies files when the Archive attribute is set on a file.  The archive attribute is set on the file when it is a new file or it has been changed. XCOPY also has the /D option.  Thought ROBOCOPY has something like that.

Comment: Correct but it compares with destination folder if file is newer it copy if not it doesn't. but I cant rely on that as files will get process and deleted from destination....so need a different approach

Comment: So I am not understanding why using the ARCHIVE attribute would not work or `XCOPY /D 10-16-2017`

Comment: Sorry I read it wrong...the /D does date....we want this to be done in real time or as close to real time as possible... so I would need something that checks date and time.... and a way for the date/time I'm checking to be from the last time the batch file copy files.

Comment: So I will ask for a third time.  What is wrong with using the Archive attribute? Any new or changed files in your source directory will have the archive attribute set. Then you can use the /M swith with XCOPY or ROBOCOPY which will copy all the new and changed files to the destination.  Once they are done copying to the destination the archive attribute on those files will be turned off.

Comment: Got it that work! Sorry I'm not familiar with these commands at all....last question...is there a way I can only copy certain files ending in a specific format? For example the source folder will have 4 files [ xxxxx-ip.txt, xxxx-chr.txt, xxxxx-hdr.txt] etc....only want the two of those ending ing IP.txt and CHR.txt

Comment: Robocopy syntax says it all. **ROBOCOPY source destination [file [file]...] [options]**  Where file is: **file :: File(s) to copy  (names/wildcards: default is "*.*").** So you could do `robocopy c:\source c:\destination *ip.txt *chr.txt /M`

Comment: …or perhaps use **/XF file [file]... :: eXclude Files matching given names/paths/wildcards.** `RoboCopy "C:\source" "C:\destination" *-*.txt /M /XF *-hdr.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I think the [REPLACE](https://ss64.com/nt/replace.html) command is what you need:

```
REPLACE "C:\Source" "C:\Destination" /U
```

From replace help message:

> /U                       Replaces (updates) only files that are older than
>                            source files. Cannot use with the /A switch.

It also accepts wildcards.

Comment: I don't need to replace I need to copy from source to destination for processing...I cant use destination as a way to check since once files hit destination folder a software I'm using will grab, process and delete those files...